# Add an String value to a Integer SelectOption list - convert String to Integer

Tags: apex, string, selectoption, convert

I got the following list of integer SelectOptions, and I want to add a String value to the SelectOption list. How can I convert String to Integer to add the String value?

'recordLimit' is an integer value I have declared in the controller.

Any help on this is appreciated.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!isBuildReport}" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Record Limit" />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!recordLimit}" size="1" multiselect="false" >
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10" />
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="50" itemLabel="50" />
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="100" itemLabel="100" />
                        <!-- <apex:selectOption itemValue="All" itemLabel="All" /> -->
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in All, you want a sumatory of all values you can use that

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!isBuildReport}" >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Record Limit" />
                <apex:selectList value="{!recordLimit}" size="1" multiselect="false" >
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="50" itemLabel="50" />
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="100" itemLabel="100" />
                    <!-- <apex:selectOption itemValue="160" itemLabel="All" /> -->
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: What is different in your code?

Comment: @BarCotter difference is he has given a itemValue to the String itemLabel

Comment: The only difference I can see is that you changed `itemValue="ALL"` to `itemValue="160"` in the line that is commented out.

Comment: Yes, I had the issue in that line so that's why it was commented out. Tried with Torsen's solution and it works fine !